# Flask parse query string from request.args

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have a Flask GET endpoint that can accept several arguments. What I would like to have is generic request.args validator (for limiting only that parameters, that I need; any other - `400 Bad request`) and request.args data type parser, instead of using `request.args.get(parameter, type, default)`.

I was thinking about `request.query_string` and using `string.split` try to parse the parameter names and the values. My args can be a lists, int, or string like in simple example:

`0.0.0.0:5000/roads?type=highway&countryIds=[1,2,3]`

Any thoughts about how do it with the best practice?

Comment: `request.args` is a dictionary so you can use `for`-loop to check every element - you don't have to use `query_string` for this. If you find element which is not on your list then you can raise error. ie. `for key, value in request.args.items(): print(key, value)`

Comment: @furas that can be some idea, but what about parsing the fields to their types, like list? Any values passes in query string are str.

Comment: it may not be safe but you can use `data = eval('[1,2,3]') ; type(data)` . OR you will have to create own parser. Even `route("<int:name>")` doesn't have method to check list - only `string`,`int`,`float`,`path`. https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#built-in-converters

Comment: see also custon converter for `route()` https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#custom-converters

Comment: @furas I'll try that approach